# Angular, IF statement in template

Tags: angular

I have this code in template:

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users | async" class="beacon-label me" [ngStyle]="{ 'top':user.posY+'px', 'left':user.posX+'px' }" >
      <div class="userId"><p>{{user.$key}}</p></div>
</div>
```

This code shows all users, but i don't want to show users with some specific attributes (user with age under 15). I tried ngIf, but it didnt work.

Comment: I have tagged your question under `angular`, since `angularjs` is for questions related to angularjs v1.+

Comment: I don't see your `*ngIf`, or what happened when you did it, or what you really mean by "doesn't work"..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `ng-template` for that

```
<ng-template ngFor let-user [ngForOf]="users | async">
   <div class="beacon-label me" [ngStyle]="{ 'top':user.posY+'px', 'left':user.posX+'px' }" >
      <div *ngIf="user.age < 15" class="userId"><p>{{user.$key}}</p></div>
   </div>
</ng-template>
```

where the `*ngIf` is - put your predicate.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users | async" class="beacon-label me" [ngStyle]="{ 'top':user.posY+'px', 'left':user.posX+'px' }" >
      <div class="userId" 
           *ngIf="user.age < 15"> <!-- Change age with appropriate user key you are looping -->
               <p>{{user.$key}}</p>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would have been simpler to put `filter` over the `users` Observable. Utilize the power provided by Observable.

```
//Assuming getUser method is method of userService returns `Observable`
this.users = this.userService.getUser().filter(user => user.age < 15)
```